# restarting to main function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am making a macronutrient calculator. This this calculator if the user makes an error calculator simply restarts and goes back to the main(). However, I believe my use of main() in my code causes the display of 2 runs of the code

Here is the link to my code: http://pastebin.com/FMqf2aRS

```
    *******Welcome to the MACRONUTRIENT CALCULATOR********
    Enter your calorie deficit: 30
    Percentage of Protein: 30
    Percent of Carbohydrates: 40
    Percentage of Fats: 40
    Total percentages surpassed 100! Please reenter percentages.
    *******Welcome to the MACRONUTRIENT CALCULATOR********
    Enter your calorie deficit: 2200
    Percentage of Protein: 30
    Percent of Carbohydrates: 30
    Percentage of Fats: 40
    You must eat 660.0 calories of protein which is equivalent to 165.0 grams of protein.
    You must eat 880.0 calories of fat which is equivalent to 97.7777777778 grams of fat.
    You must eat 660.0 calories of carbohydrates which is equivalent to 73.3333333333 grams of carbohydrates.
    You must eat 9.0 calories of protein which is equivalent to 2.25 grams of protein.
    You must eat 12.0 calories of fat which is equivalent to 1.33333333333 grams of fat.
    You must eat 12.0 calories of carbohydrates which is equivalent to 1.33333333333 grams of carbohydrates.
```

Is there a different way of approaching this to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Sure, instead of going back to `main`, go back to someplace that just does the calculations. You can do this (for example) by taking all the `input` and calculations and so on out of `main` and putting it in a function called `run`. Then `main` calls `run()` after printing the welcome message, and if you need to try again, you call `run` again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `main()` the way you are doing it is the wrong way to solve this. You're pushing more and more `main()` calls onto the stack - eventually the program will crash if you enter invalid entries too many times in a row. You should use a `while` loop as shown below

```
def main():
  while True:
      print "*******Welcome to the MACRONUTRIENT CALCULATOR********"
      calorie_deficit = float(input("Enter your calorie deficit: "))
      Percent_protein = float(input("Percentage of Protein: "))
      Percent_carb = float(input("Percent of Carbohydrates: "))
      Percent_fat = float(input("Percentage of Fats: "))
      Macro_dict = {'Protein': Percent_protein, 'Carbohydrate': Percent_carb, 'Fats': Percent_fat}
      Macro_sum = Percent_protein + Percent_carb + Percent_fat
      if not Total_Macro_Check(Macro_sum):
          continue
      Macro_percentage_to_calorie(calorie_deficit, Percent_protein, Percent_carb, Percent_fat)


def Total_Macro_Check(total_val):
  if total_val > 100:
    print "Total percentages surpassed 100! Please reenter percentages."
    return False
  if total_val < 100:
    print "Total precentages is less than 100! Please reenter precentages."
    return False
  return True
```

Comment: The default recursion limit is 1000. You need to eat a lot to reach this. ;)

Comment: @MikeMüller, that's missing the point. Calling main() recursively was not the intent, so it's a bug. Bugs that don't show up most of the time can be very hard to track down.

Comment: @gnibbler You are right about the intent. I was alluding to the reason about filling the stack with frames. This is typically not a problem for an interactive program like this.

Answer (score 1):

The code is doing exactly what you tell it to do:

```
def Total_Macro_Check(total_val):
  if total_val > 100:
    print "Total percentages surpassed 100! Please reenter percentages."
    main()
  if total_val < 100:
    print "Total precentages is less than 100! Please reenter precentages."
    main()
```

You call main again.